# state_hovered Google TV

Tags: xml, selector, google-tv

Anyone know how to get state_hovered to be recognized on GoogleTv?  I realize this is new as of level 14 Android 4.0 so I just would have thought the tv would recognize it too.  Here is my layout and xml selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:orientation="vertical"> 

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/zoom_in"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@xml/zoom_in_selector" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/zoom_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@xml/zoom_out_selector" />

</LinearLayout> 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/plus_downpressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/plus_highlight" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/plus_highlight" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/plus" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google TV is currently API 12, not 14.  So, it's not possible.  That said, you can use onGenericMotion event in code to implement hover.